# What Can I Build With This

Tags: city, set-identification

I have a set of LEGO pieces that I bought second hand. I know it's a full set, because the bag was unopened, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to build with it.

[image: Lego Set]

Comment: Just because it's a sealed bag doesn't make it a full set. Most sets have lots of bags in the box.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the occurrence of the 2x2x3 brick in white and the 16 trans-blue garage door panels, I think this is a bag from [set 7744: Police Headquarters](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=7744-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ii%22:1%7D).
[image]

From the picture it looks like your bag builds the bottom right part of the station - the 2 car garages and the platform under the stairs.